# Average every N rows by column

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

I have four matrices that are 240x30. I need to calculate an average for every 15 rows and I need to do this by column. So, in the end I should have 30 columns with 16 values.

So, for instance:

```
myMatrix = randi(240,30)
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
averageBins = 15;
meanByBinsMyMatrix = arrayfun(@(i) mean(myMatrix (i:i+averageBins-1)),1:averageBins:length(myMatrix )-averageBins+1)'; % the averaged vectormean()
```

This seems to be working but I think it only does the job for the first column.
How can I extend this to work over each column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`reshape()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your first dimension a to 15-by-n matrix, leaving the columns as third dimension. Then take the mean over the first dimensions, i.e. your blocks of `n` rows. Since this will result in a `1x16x30` matrix in your case, [`squeeze()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) out the last dimension.

```
n = 15;
A = rand(240,30);
B = reshape(A,[n, size(A,1)/n, size(A,2)]); %crashes for size(A,1)/n != integer
C = squeeze(mean(B,1)); % Calculate the mean over the first dimension
```

---

#### A short introduction to `reshape()` in multiple dimensions.

Create a small matrix, say `magic(4)`, for visualisation:

```
A = magic(4)
A =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

This is a four column matrix. Now, if we reshape it to a 2x2x4 matrix, where do our dimensions go? Let's try it:

```
B = reshape(A,[2,2,4])
B(:,:,1) =
    16     9
     5     4
B(:,:,2) =
     2     7
    11    14
B(:,:,3) =
     3     6
    10    15
B(:,:,4) =
    13    12
     8     1
```

What happened? The first column of `A` contains `[16;5;9;4]`. The first "page", which is the first entry on the third dimension, of `B` contains exactly these numbers!

`reshape()` works *column-wise*, meaning that it "walks" through the initial matrix going (1,1)->(2,1)->(3,1) etc, until the end of the first column is reached. Then it starts reading at (1,2)->(2,2)->(3,2) etc.
As to the storing part: MATLAB stores them in the same order, thus column wise. When it has filled up a dimension, it will increase the next dimension index by 1 and keep on filling. Thus, the 1x4 first column of `A` gets stored as `[16;5]` first, then the second column is filled, making the first page of `B(:,:,1) = [16 9;5 4]`, i.e. it started filling the second column of the first page. Now that the first page is full, the second column of `A` gets put into the second page of `B` in the same way, the third column goes to the third page and so on and so forth, until all elements in `A` are copied.

*Note: this is why the "size" parameter of `reshape` is so important, it tells the program when to start in the next dimension. The product of your sizes, i.e. the number of elements, cannot change during this operation!*

After doing this in the original case, you end up with a 15-by-16-by-30 matrix. Meaning that you have 30 pages, your original columns, which 16 columns each, the number of blocks, of 15 rows, being the number of elements in each group.

Then `mean(B,1)` tells `mean` to take the mean over the *first* dimension, which are the elements in each of your blocks, and that across all blocks and pages.

The only minor thing left is that MATLAB doesn't strip off non-trailing singleton dimensions by default, so you end up with a 1-by-16-by-30 matrix. `squeeze()`, finally, strips out all the singleton dimensions, leaving you with a 16-by-30 matrix, containing the average of each block of 15 elements in the corresponding row/column location.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) to compute the mean of each group of rows. This works even if the number of rows is not a multiple of the group size (the last group has fewer rows):

```
result = splitapply(@(x)mean(x,1), myMatrix, floor((0:size(myMatrix,1)-1)/averageBins).'+1);
```