# Displaying a matrix obtained from a vectorised structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am trying to extract the coordinates located in the variable `x` within a .mat structure. I would like to print them as a three column matrix. Let's say:

```
-5543837.67700032 -2054567.16633347 2387852.25825667
 4641938.565315761 393003.28157792 4133325.70392322
 -3957408.7414133 3310229.46968631 3737494.72491701
 1492206.38965564 -4458130.51073730 4296015.51539152
 4075539.69798060 931735.497964395 4801629.46009471
 3451207.69353006 3060375.44622100 4391915.05780934
```

I know that I can get them with

```matlab
file=load('./filee_scan.mat')
stat = [file.scan.stat]';
x = [stat.x]';
```

But I get something like:

```
-5543837.67700032
-2054567.16633347
 2387852.25825667
 4641938.565315761
 393003.28157792
 4133325.70392322
 % :: and so on
```

I would like to print them as I showed at the beginning (`x` as a vector of 3 coordinates and one line per station) but I don't know how to treat them. I have tried with loops but I really don't know how to express them.

How can I display my coordinates as an n *-by-* 3 matrix?

This is the scan file:
[image: scan file]

This is `x`:
[image: x variable]

Comment: Thanks, I does not solve the problem. It just show all decimals... What I want is to see the vector X for each entry. I don't care about the format.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but if I understand correctly, you want to be able to see your variable's values in decimal notation inside the variable explorer ? That can be adjusted here:  [Preferences->Variables](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html)

Comment: OK. the variable x (in my opinion) it is a vector (of 3 coordinates) inside a vector. So, I want to print it as I put it at the beginning of the post. Like x(n,3), being n the total number of lines in the whole file. At this stage, I don't care about the decimal format. I just want a matrix of (nx3) instead of a vector of 3n.

Comment: I edited the question and modified the output I get in order to show that my question is not related to the decimal format.

Comment: Yes! I want a 3-column matrix. The command that I have used is written in the post and the output too (i wrote it in the end). The structure of the data can be seen in the pictures. But I really don't know how to express this in matlab language. How can I indicate the structure of data in order to get what I want?

Comment: As a note to my edits, which you reverted, [salutations are not acceptable in the Stack Overflow model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/325771). SO is a question and answer wiki-style site, not a personal help desk, hence "thanks", names, etc are removed from posts. Second, "meta-info" like "I'm new to MATLAB" have no bearing on any possible solution and should thus neither be in the question.

Comment: Additionally, please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. Thus in this case, a simple 2 field structure would've been better.

Answer (score 0):

`[stat.x].'` gives you a flattened vector, as you've seen. You can [`reshape()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) that vector to the desired format:

```matlab
x = reshape(x,3,[]).';
```

This reshapes first to 3 rows and `n` columns (your number of stations), then transposed to have `n` rows of 3 columns.

---

For a short introduction on how `reshape` works, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214501/average-every-n-rows-by-column/59214608#59214608).