# Split dataset to specific number of sample by for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sample

I have a 35136-by-1 matrix containing power data of 366 days with every day having 96 measurements). I want to take a sample from 252 days: power data of "day 1 to day 7" is the first sample, power data of "day 2 to day 8" is the second sample, etc.), and reshape my matrix to size `[96 7 1 252]`. 
I wrote following code, but I get 36 sample instead of 252

```matlab
m=7;
for j=1
    sample([j:96*m],:)=solarpower_n([j:96*m],:);
    y([(96*m)+1:96*(m+1)],:)=solarpower_n([(96*m)+1:96*(m+1)],:);
    m=m+1;
    for j=2:246
        sample([(96*(j-1))+1:96*m],:)=solarpower_n([(96*(j-1))+1:96*m],:);
        y([(96*m)+1:96*(m+1)],:)=solarpower_n([(96*m)+1:96*(m+1)],:);
        m=m+1;
    end
end
```

I want to take sample from each 7 days. Assume `D` to be the number of days, and `M` as number of power measurements on each day. For 252 days, `M=[1,2,3,...,96]` and `D=[1,2,...,252]` . Thus the power of first day, `P1`, has a dimension of 96*1. I want to take `sample1={P1,...,P7}, sample2={P2,...,P8} , .....,sample252={P246,.....,P252}`. and have a `[96 7 1 252]` 4-D array.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `96*7*1*252 = 169344` which is not equal to 35136, so reshaping that won't work, as in reshape the number of elements should not change. Can you please [edit] the question to add a [mcve], i.e. code that we can run? Include a small sample of your data (or random data if you can't share the original), e.g. 2 or 3 days worth of data, and demonstrate what you want to have sampled to where. 96 by 252 is easy (`reshape(data(1:96*252),[96 252])`), but where does your second dimension of size 7 come from?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to take sample from each 7 days. let's get "D" as number of days, and "M" as number of power measurement in each day. for 252 days,  M={1,2,3,...,96} and D={1,2,...,252} . so, power of first day, P1, have 96*1 dimension. I want to take sample1={P1,...,P7}, sample2={P2,...,P8} , .....,sample252={P246,.....,P252}. and have a [96 7 1 252] 4-D array.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Do **NOT** paste data or code as images, as we cannot copy-paste them into our machines. Instead, paste data as-is, i.e. as text. Aditionally, add all relevant information to the question itself, rather than in ephemeral comments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking samples that way is rather inefficient, since you're copying each data point 7 times. You could simply use indexing:

```matlab
A = rand(96*366, 1);  % Sample data
B = reshape(A,[96 366]); % Reshape all your days in one go
B(:, 1:7) % first 7 days
B(:, 163:170) % Days 163 to 170, etc.
```

If you do want to copy your data seven times to your 4D array you can use a simple `for` loop:

```matlab
A = rand(96*366, 1);  % Sample data
% Note you need days 253:256, since P252 contains those days
B = reshape(A(1:96*(252+6)),[96 (252+6)]); % Reshape your first 252 days

C = zeros(size(B,1), 7, 1, size(B,2)-6);  % Initialise output

for ii = 1:size(B,2)-6
   C(:, :, :, ii) = B(:, ii:ii+6);  % Save each 7 day sample
end
```

Getting rid of the `for` loop is difficult, given you want a sliding window. There are probably specialised functions for that somewhere, but given your data size a loop should be sufficiently performant.

For a short introduction on `reshape()` you can read [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214608/5211833).

Comment: thanks for your helpful response, I undrestand it. I also want to take {P8},{P9},...,{Pq} as q-by-1 matrix, where q is number of sample, how should I define this?

Comment: `A = solarpower_n;  % Sample data
B = reshape(A(1:96*(252+6)),[96 (252+6)]); 
ytrain = zeros(size(B,1), 1, size(B,2));  
for ii = 1:size(B,2)-6
end` is this code right?