# Optimize a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

This is my code:

```
variables=1000;
t=20;
x=zeros(t,t,3);
y=rand(variables,3);
z=rand(t,t,variables);
e=rand(variables,1);
for c=1:variables
            x(:,:,1)=x(:,:,1)+y(c,1).*((z(:,:,c)-e(c)).^2);
            x(:,:,2)=x(:,:,2)+y(c,2).*((z(:,:,c)-e(c)).^2);
            x(:,:,3)=x(:,:,3)+y(c,3).*((z(:,:,c)-e(c)).^2);
end
```

How can I improve calculation speed on this loop? I think that the problem is the `for` loop with a large `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a myth, but alas a persistent one, that loops are slow in MATLAB.  As you've written your `for` loop, it goes sequentially through the last dimension of your variables. That pretty much translates to a FORTRAN loop directly, leaving little room for improvement using vectorisation. The below does vectorise your output as much as possible, but doesn't improve performance much, even though `reshape()` is almost free, and severely degrades readability.

In each iteration, all you're doing is calculating `y(c,1).*((z(:,:,c)-e(c)).^2)`, which is added to the total. If we are able to vectorise that expression, we can sum over the dimension of `c` to get rid of the loop.

`z(:,:,c)-e(c)` can be vectorised by adding two singleton dimensions to `e`: `reshape(e, [1 1 numel(e)])`, then subtract and power by 2 as usual.

Multiplication by  `y(c,1)` also works, if we add two singleton dimensions to `y(:,1)`:, `reshape(y(:,1), [1 1 numel(e)])`, then multiply again as usual.

Finally, we just need to sum over our 3rd dimension and we end up with our `t` *-by-* `t` result: `sum(tmp2, 3)`.

All that's left are the hardcoded three dimensions in `x`, which I've left be in a loop.

The working code on R2007b:

```
variables=10;
t=2;
x=zeros(t,t,3);
y=rand(variables,3);
z=rand(t,t,variables);
e=rand(variables,1);

for ii = 1:size(x, 3)
    x(:, :, ii) = sum(bsxfun(@times, reshape(y(:,1), [1 1 numel(e)]), bsxfun(@minus, z, reshape(e, [1 1 numel(e)])).^2), 3);
end
```

I wasn't sure what to do with the hardcoded dimension of `3`, so I just left a loop over that. The rest is vectorised away, thanks to a few `reshape()` calls to arrange the dimensions for the `bsxfun()` expansion.

Code for >R2016b with implicit expansion:

```
for ii = 1:size(x, 3)
    x(:, :, ii) = sum(reshape(y(:,ii), [1 1 numel(e)]) .* (z -  reshape(e, [1 1 numel(e)])).^2, 3)
end
```

A quick timing comparison shows that this is roughly 2x faster than your original loop:

```
Elapsed time is 0.780516 seconds. Original code
Elapsed time is 0.397369 seconds. My bsxfun() solution
Elapsed time is 0.305160 seconds. My implicit expansion
```

Note that in the above a 100 loops were ran for each code version, i.e. timings are 8ms, 4ms and 3ms per version.

---

For an introduction to [`reshape()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) you can refer to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214608/5211833).
The [documentation article on implicit broadcasting](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html) is rather good, as is [this blog](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/).